# Unable to close login window or go to HomePage in makeMyTrip.com

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am trying to automate the MakeMyTrip website using selenium, when I am running the tests, the login window is blocking all other elements on a page.

1. I tried to click somewhere else on the page to get rid of the login page not working.
2. Tried to login after providing username and password, but OTP is there and we cannot automate them.

**Test Steps:**

1. Select RoundTrip checkbox.
2. Select From and To:
3. Select dates and search.

**Issue:** Unable to get rid of login window.

**Screen:**

[image: Login Screen blocking]

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: When did you get this pop up ? I tried manually.. it did not show up at all

Comment: Yes unfortunately thats the intermittent popup . You can click on the login tab. if you want to see it manually click on login or create account . My all tests are failing due to this pop up

Comment: so basically you are saying when you fill those login input with valid values and click in login button, it does not disappear ?

Comment: I couldnt take that login path - because once u enter username and password , It sends the OPT .. so basically just wanted to get rid of login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click with Actions somewhere out of that pop-up.
I use the following method for this and it works fine:

```
public void clickAction(By element){
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(element);
    action.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement).build().perform();
}
```

```
By logo = By.xpath("//a[@data-cy="mmtLogo"]");
clickAction(logo);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@data-cy='account']/div[contains(@class,'autopop')]")).isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@data-cy='account']")).click();
        }
```